# How to wait for a new different jframe to close before continuing execution to first jFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have 3 classes called on a button action perfomed. After one class is called  a new jframe appears and a user must complete some dates. I would like that the second and third class to be called after the user close the second jFrame. 
The question (and i appreciate any suggestions) is how can i implement an action in the first frame that 'knows' when the other frame is closed?

```
 insertUser insertUserX=new insertUser(name,user,pass);
 new AddDates(xText1,xText2,xText3,xText4).setVisible(true);
    //here the second jFrame appears and i wouldd like to stop the executin until the frame is closed
 checkData xCheckData = new checkData(); 
 update xUpdate = new update(name, user, pass);
```

Comment: Don't use two JFrames here, but instead this is the perfect situation for a modal dialog such as a JOptionPane or a modal JDialog. The dialog will prevent code flow in the calling code until the dialog is no longer visible.

Comment: See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint. I solved this with a jDialog; it worked perfect.